# Angular - Reset Observable shape after sort is applied

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I want to reset the shape of my Observable after a sort is applied. When the user applies the top revenue filter, the data is sorted accordingly. When the user removes the filter, this sorting should be removed.

Here is the logic:

```
movieList$!: Observable<Movie[]>;

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.movieList$ = this.apiManager.fetchMovies().pipe(map(movieList => movieList.content), shareReplay());
}

filterByTopRevenue() {
    ...
    this.movieList$ = this.movieList$.pipe(map(movieList => movieList.sort((movieA, movieB) => movieB.revenue - movieA.revenue).slice(0, 10)));
}

resetFilters() {
    ...
    // reset movieList$ shape to the original not sorted shape
}
```

And here is the template:

```
<tr *ngFor='let movie of movieList$ | async' (click)="selectMovie(movie.id)">
    <td class="movie-entry ranking">{{ movie.rank }}</td>
    <td class="movie-entry">{{ movie.title }}</td>
    <td class="movie-entry">{{ movie.year }}</td>
    <td class="movie-entry">{{ movie.revenue | revenuePipe }}</td>
</tr>
```

How can I reset the Observable to its original shape, keeping the reactive design?

Comment: you need to make sure you keep an original movielist in diff variable so just filter always within that list.

Comment: How can I do that without an explicit subscription? Can I make a copy of the `movieList$` Observable somehow? I want to prioritize subscriptions at the level of the template.

Comment: if you don't want to copy, you can use pipe to transform while displaying.

Comment: @ManuelBrás Use this as reference [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-table-async)

Comment: @NarenMurali I looked through it but it's a bit complex to fully understand what is happening.

Comment: @ManuelBrás Reactive programming has a steep learning curve, else just do a subscribe and get it done!

Comment: use `switchMap` ?
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tnspwv